# What's the simplest way to remotely access a simple EJB running on Glassfish?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6

I'm novice in Java EE, and to get started, I used this tutorial:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

I don't want to change anything, but I want to access the EJB remotely.

Which is the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `JNDI` look ups as mentioned [here](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB).

Comment: I don't know how to apply it to my code. I think it's related to some Glassfish setting.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks for the answer, I finally got the solution.